# WebGL texture: second time load sizing is wrong

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a WebGL `canvas` in which I load two images as textures. For each texture load, I first resize the canvas to the image size, so that the image is not distorted.

Despite the resizing, the second texture is distorted. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fK96j/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. One needs to use the `gl.viewport` function.